# Nuxt 3, Vercel deploy only one edge function

Tags: vercel, nuxt3, edge-function

I have a Nuxt 3 app that I deployed on Vercel. I'm wondering if there's a way to deploy only one of my endpoints as an edge function, while the rest remain as serverless functions. I tried configuring it with 'runtime: "edge"'

```
export const config = {
  runtime: "edge",
}
```

but it didn't work, as all of them still seem to be serverless functions.

If I set the 'nitro' preset, all of my functions become edge functions. However that's not what I want. I only need one endpoint to be an edge function.

Is that currently possible with nuxt 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nitro is not supporting this kind of behavior yet but it's in their roadmap, see: https://github.com/unjs/nitro/issues/1120